# Collision between two objects not detected after performing a move action on one of them

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I seem to have a poor understanding of something related to collision detections, actions or positions in `SpriteKit`.

I have a player and bricks and when a player lands on any brick, he jumps of it and then all bricks move down for a certain distance. I have the player added as a child of the scene and the bricks as children of a node (`SKNode`) containing them. When I want to change their y-position, I just use a `moveBy` action on that node and the bricks do indeed move how I want them to.

The problem is, when they are moving or even when they stop, the player can't land on them anymore (collision between them and the player is not detected anymore), so the player just falls through them.

This is my code in `GameScene.swift`:

```
func moveBricksDownFor(movedForY: CGFloat) {
    let moveAction = SKAction.moveBy(CGVectorMake(0, -movedForY), duration: 1.0)
    brickNode.runAction(moveAction)
    for _ in 0...4 {addBrick(0.7)}
}

func playerCollidedWithBrick(brick: Brick) {
    if player.position.y > brick.position.y {
        player.physicsBody?.velocity.dy = player.maxVelocityY
    }
    if player.yChangedFor() > 70 {moveBricksDownFor(player.yChangedFor())}
}
```

Is it possible that physics body isn't attached to visual representations of the bricks or something like this?

Here is also the `Player` class (the parts used in the above code):

```
let maxVelocityY: CGFloat = 900
var startPositionY: CGFloat!

init(position: CGPoint) {
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "doodler.png")
    super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.blackColor(), size: CGSizeMake(60, 60))
    self.zPosition = Layer.player.rawValue
    self.position = position
    self.startPositionY = position.y
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.size)
    self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    self.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
    self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Brick
    self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
    self.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
}

func yChangedFor() -> CGFloat {
    return (self.position.y - startPositionY)
}
```

I did google similar topics but didn't find any similar problems so I guess I am missing something fundamental here or am making a stupid mistake.

**UPDATE** (added the `Brick` class and initialization of `worldNode` (`SKNode`)):

```
class Brick: SKSpriteNode { 
    init(position:CGPoint) {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "brick.png")
        super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeMake(70, 10))
        self.position = position
        self.zPosition = Layer.brick.rawValue
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.size)
        self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
        self.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Brick
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
        self.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    }
}
```

Setting the `brickNode` and adding bricks to it as its children:

```
func setupBrickNode() {
    brickNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    brickNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
}

func addBrick(minXPercantage: CGFloat) {
    let randomX = random(min: size.width*0.25, max: size.width - 100)
    let randomY = random(min: size.height*minXPercantage, max: size.height)
    let brick = Brick(position: CGPointMake(randomX, randomY))
    brickNode.addChild(brick)
}

func setupBricks() {
    for _ in 0...10 {addBrick(0.25)}
}
```

Updated the part where I move the `brickNode` (now with setting its velocity):

```
func moveBricks() {
    brickNode.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, -player.maxVelocityY/4)
    let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0)
    let setBrickNodeVelocityToZero = SKAction.runBlock({self.brickNode.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)})
    runAction(SKAction.sequence([waitAction, setBrickNodeVelocityToZero]))
}

func playerCollidedWithBrick(brick: Brick) {
    if player.position.y > brick.position.y {
        player.physicsBody?.velocity.dy = player.maxVelocityY
        moveBricks()
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at my second answer. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example code

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var world: SKNode!
    var player: SKSpriteNode!

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -10)

        // World
        world = SKNode()
        addChild(world)

        // Player
        player = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
        player.position.x = size.width / 2

        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: player.size)
        player.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = 2
        player.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = 4
        player.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0
        player.physicsBody!.mass = 1
        player.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 2000)
        player.physicsBody!.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

        world.addChild(player)

        // Bricks
        for index in 0...50 {
            // Player
            let brick = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.greenColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 25))
            brick.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: 300 + CGFloat(index) * 200)
            brick.zPosition = -1

            brick.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: brick.size)
            brick.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = 4
            brick.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = 2
            brick.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0
            brick.physicsBody!.dynamic = false

            world.addChild(brick)
        }
    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        // Is the player falling?
        guard player.physicsBody!.velocity.dy <= 0 else {
            return
        }

        player.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 1000)
    }

    override func didFinishUpdate() {
        guard player.position.y > 200 else {
            return
        }

        world.position.y = -player.position.y + 200
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to land to a dynamic involved object probably you must set this.

```
self.physicsBody!.restitution = 0
```

Also, it's not the best attitude using `SKAction`'s moveBy instead of correct motion by velocity or force vectors, this can be change your physics object values and you lost their directions.

Comment: I did not know that, thank you. Could you explain why I should set the restitution to zero? Does this affect physic bodies in any other way than to make them bounce when collision occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Because particular brick position is always the same. You are moving it's parent not the brick itself.

```
let realBrickPosition = convertPoint(brick.position, toNode: self)
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the problem? Wouldn't the player then just collide on the wrong places but still collide and jump of something? Before moving he jumps of off every brick he lands on, but if I try to move them, he can't land on any of them and just falls through them.

Comment: It's hard to tell without looking at the game. I would just use didBeginContact / didEndContact to detect ... contact between brick and the player.

Comment: Do bricks have physics body?

Comment: Yes, I do use didBeginContact to detect the collisions.. They are set so they do not collide with bricks but do contact the SKPhysicsContact when in contact and then call the playerCollidedWithBrick function, which makes a player jump and moves the brickNode, which is a SKNode containing all the bricks.

Comment: I tried moving the brickNode by setting its velocity and the same thing happens - collisions between the player and the bricks is not being detected. Is it a wrong approach to use a SKNode that has children and move it instead of moving each child by itself?

Comment: So brickNode has physics body and every brick also has physics body? Can you edit your post to show how you create brick node and bricks?